# how to configure mutual certificate authentication

Tags: wildfly, java-ee-7, client-certificates

Am trying to accomplish client certificate authentication using wildfly 8.2, I have changed logging level to ALL to enable me see errors from org.jboss.security

(NOTE:passwords used are for demonstration)

below is my configuration in wildfly 8.2 standalone.xml

```
<security-realm name="SSLRealm">
    <server-identities>
        <ssl protocol="TLSv1">
            <keystore path="localhost.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="localhost" alias="localhost"/>
        </ssl>
    </server-identities>
    <authentication>
        <truststore path="cacerts.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="localhost"/>
    </authentication>
</security-realm>
```

my security domain

```
<security-domain name="client-cert-policy" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Certificate" flag="required">
            <module-option name="securityDomain" value="client-cert-policy"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
    <jsse keystore-password="localhost" keystore-url="file:/${jboss.server.config.dir}/localhost.jks" truststore-password="localhost" truststore-url="file:/${jboss.server.config.dir}/cacerts.jks" client-auth="true"/>
</security-domain>
```

my https-listerner

```
<https-listener name="default-https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SSLRealm" verify-client="REQUESTED"/>
```

in my web application web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>allpages</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>all-res</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description/>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>client-cert-policy</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

in jboss.xml

```
<context-root>/haven</context-root>
<security-domain>client-cert-policy</security-domain>
```

Despite all this my web application returns a 403 error page

Any help will be greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got the client_auth to work the following are the modification are made

in standalone.xml security domain changed from Certificate to CertificateRoles, add a role property file

```
<security-domain name="client-cert-policy" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="CertificateRoles" flag="required">
            <module-option name="securityDomain" value="client-cert-policy"/>
            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/user_roles.properties"/>
            <module-option name="defaultRolesProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/default_roles.properties"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
    <jsse keystore-password="localhost" keystore-url="file:/${jboss.server.config.dir}/localhost.jks" truststore-password="localhost" truststore-url="file:/${jboss.server.config.dir}/cacerts.jks" client-auth="true"/>
</security-domain>
```

modified web.xml to add the roles

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>allpages</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>all-res</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>sys_view</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description/>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>client-cert-policy</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>sys_view</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Comment: could you post the files user_roles.properties and user_roles.properties I think maybe it could help me in a similar situation.